# Как поменять подсветку текущих переменных в коде Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Народ помогите плиз, где найти как меняется подсветка в коде редактора WebStorm.
Я не вижу одинаковых переменных. Они сливаюся с остальным текстом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал менять так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но не помогает. Почему не меняет? Как сделать чтобы меняло? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно поменять параметры (цвет, например) и сохранить новое название схеми и выбрать его в выпадающем спиcке Scheme name
[image: скрин]

Comment: Я все так и сделал, только вот подсветку он не поменял http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0015/2419/1038707/160225/250df8fa55.jpg

Comment: @dimaua, а Search result (write access) меняли подсветку?

Comment: да вот http://joxi.ru/RmzbkGpSWwKjym